# How can I find the key in a dict whose matching value, which is a list, contains X?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a python dictionary which maps a number of words to lists of other words. E.g:

```
d = {"Hello": ["hi", "hello", "hey", "yo"],
     "Goodbye": ["bye", "see ya", "goodbye", "laters"]}
```

Given a lowercase word, I want to check whether that word is in any of the dictionary values and retrieve the corresponding key.

I'm sure there is some elegant solution using some of pythons' functional capabilities (`itertools` perhaps) but its just beyond my reach...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can have *multiple* keys matching, so you'd need to produce a set (since order doesn't matter and keys are unique):

```
{key for key, words in d.iteritems() if search_word in words}
```

If you are only interested in the first match (because you keep your words unique, say), you can use `next()` and a generator expression:

```
next((key for key, words in d.iteritems() if search_word in words), None)
```

You probably want to create an inverse index if you need to test for multiple words:

```
reverse_index = {}
for key, words in d.iteritems():
    for word in words:
        reverse_index.setdefault(word, set()).add(key)
```

after which you can just use:

```
reverse_index.get(search_word, set())
```

to get the same result.

For unique words in your lists, the reverse index would simply be:

```
reverse_index = {word: key for key, words in d.iteritems() for word in words}
reverse_index.get(search_word)
```

Comment: no possibility of multiple keys matching as the two lists are unique? I.e. a word can only be in one of the lists and thus have one matching key. But, that aside, your solution is good!